# Change doesn't trigger when selection all checkboxes and records not getting added to the array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have checkbox in each row of the table if I check any checkbox in the table individually then checkedForDeletion() methond runs and it adds the added record in the array and removes it if unchecked however if i select the checkbox at the top in the table th heading then (change) doesn't get triggerd and records are not added and removed from the array based on checked status.
I want that if user clicks on checkbox in the heading then all records should be push to the array and removed if used unchecks anyone row and so on.

```html
    <table>
    <tr>
              <th class="id"><input type="checkbox" (change)="selectAll();" [checked]="selectedAll"></th>
              <th class="ip">IP</th>
              <th class="domain">Domain</th>
              <th class="status">Status</th>
              <th class="sender-mail">Sender Email</th>
              <th class="status">Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let record of ipRecords; let i = index;>
              <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="record.selected" (change)="checkedForDeletion(record,$event);"></td>
              <td>{{record.ip}}</td>
              <td>{{record.forDomain}}</td>
              <td>{{record.status}}</td>
              <td>{{record.senderEmail}}</td>
              <td>
              </tr>
    </table>
```

ts file

```js
    ipRecords: any;
    deletionList: any;
   selectedAll: any;

    checkedForDeletion(record: any, event: any) {
        const checked = event.target.checked;
        if (checked) {
          this.deletionList.push(record);
          console.log(this.deletionList);
        } else {
          const index = this.deletionList.findIndex(list => list.id === record.id );
          this.deletionList.splice(index, 1);
          console.log(this.deletionList);
        }

        selectAll() {
        this.selectedAll = !this.selectedAll;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ipRecords.length; i++) {
          this.ipRecords[i].selected = this.selectedAll;
      } 

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following minor changes:

1. Add an `id` to your checkboxes

   ```
   <tr *ngFor="let record of ipRecords; let i = index;>
         <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkboxId{{ i }}" [(ngModel)]="record.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected(record); checkedForDeletion(record,$event);"></td>
         <td>{{record.ip}}</td>
         <td>{{record.forDomain}}</td>
         <td>{{record.status}}</td>
         <td>{{record.senderEmail}}</td>
   </tr>
   ```
2. Update your `ts` component, to tick or untick your checkbox as appropriate

   ```
   selectAll() {
       this.selectedAll = !this.selectedAll;
       for (var i = 0; i < this.ipRecords.length; i++) {
         let box = document.getElementById('checkboxId' + i) as HTMLInputElement;
         box.checked = this.selectedAll; // toggle checked state here
         this.ipRecords[i].selected = this.selectedAll;

         let check = this.deletionList.findIndex(list => list.id === this.ipRecords[i].id );
         if (check == -1) {
            (this.selectedAll) ?  this.deletionList.push(this.ipRecords[i]) : ''; // only add if true
         } else {
            (!this.selectedAll) ? this.deletionList.splice(check, 1) : ''; // only remove if false
         }

       } 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a problem about the parameter. This is the wrong method

```
<td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="record.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected(record); checkedForDeletion(record,$event);"></td>
```

The correct method is:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="record.selected" (change)="checkIfAllSelected($event,record); checkedForDeletion($event,record);"></td>
```

There is also a parentesis problem

```
checkedForDeletion(record: any, event: any) {
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    if (checked) {
      this.deletionList.push(record);
      console.log(this.deletionList);
    } else {
      const index = this.deletionList.findIndex(list => list.id === record.id );
      this.deletionList.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(this.deletionList);
    }
}//add here to end the method above
    selectAll() {
    this.selectedAll = !this.selectedAll;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.ipRecords.length; i++) {
      this.ipRecords[i].selected = this.selectedAll;
  } 

  }
```